# Ignore space, blanks

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

Does anybody know how i could make scanner ignore space? I wanna type a first and second name, but scanner wont let me, i want to save the full name

```
String name;

System.out.print("Enter name: ");
name = scan.next(); //Ex: John Smith

System.out.println(name);
```

Edit:
New problem.. While using nextLine in my extended program, nextLine just ignores the whole question and moves on without a chance to scan the name.

Comment: if "enter name" is coming after another question, you may need to call nextLine twice - once to advance past the previous answer, and again to read the next answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Scanner#next()` splits lines around whitespace.  `Scanner.nextLine()` does not, therefore leaving spaces in.

```
name = scan.nextLine(); //Ex: John Smith
```

Answer (score 2):

use `scanner.nextLine()` which reads full line, instead of `scan.next();`

Example:

```
name = scan.nextLine();
```

Read oracle documentation for [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) class for available methods.

Answer (score 2):

`Scanner.next` delimits using whitespaces, to read a full line you can use:

```
name = scan.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, first your System.out.print(); call is flawed. Everything inside must be inside quotations
`System.out.print("Enter name: ");`

`scan.next()` gets the next character in the stream, whereas `scan.nextLine()` gets the next line (terminated by an EOL character), which may be more helpful to you.

After that, you can create an array of words, like
`String[] broken = name.split(" ");`
which will place into broken all of the words that you've typed in delimited by spaces.

Then you can go something like

```
for(int i = 0; i < broken.size; i++)
{
    System.out.print(broken[i] + " ");
}
System.out.println();
```

Comment: help, help, I'm being oppressed :(

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you want to read the entire line (minus the line ending). if someone enters, "helen r. smith", you can read the line in with:

```
name = scan.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

YOU CAN DO LIKE THIS

```
import java.util.*;
class scanner2
{
public static void main(String args[])
    {
    Scanner in= new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter the name");
    String name= in.nextLine();//for name with spaces with more than one word or for    one word.

    System.out.println("enter single word");
    String rl= in.next();//single word name

    System.out.println("name is "+name+"  rl is "+rl);

    }

}
```

Execute it you will get your answer.